# Fail to add an HTTP header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, http-headers

I'm trying to produce an HTTP request with an Authorization header:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "https://subdomain.domain.com/login",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password'));
            }})
```

But the request that's produced by this code does not contain an Authorization header:

> OPTIONS /login HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: subdomain.domain.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
> Origin: http://localhost:3021
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/12.3.4567.890 Safari/537.36
>
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Referer: http://localhost:3021/app.html
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ttried using `headers` key in AJAX request syntext???

Comment: @ShalinPatel no, what do you mean? can you give me an example please?

Comment: like `headers : {"Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password') }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to make a cross-domain request do a server that does not allow CORS.

Therefore, the request I saw was a preflight request that used the OPTIONS method. If in this preflight request I had gotten the proper response CORS header, I would see my Authorization header in the real request. But since I did not pass the preflight OPTIONS request, I didn't have a real request, and therefore I didn't see the Authorization header.

I solved it by consuming the API using Node.js rather than the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This may Solve your Problem.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://subdomain.domain.com/login",
    headers : {
                "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password') 
    }
})
```